# ASP.NET MVC and Listener/Event

Tags: asp.net-mvc, events, listener

I would like to improve my knowledge, because I notice several time, I am convince I develop without to use the right practices, exemple to export a csv in ASP.NET MVC, I create in the controler 4 private methods, these methods do the necessary and return data.
I combine in 1 method, the 4 methods and call the parent method when the use click on export CSV.
These 4 methods are used in two places differents. So I can factorize the code in one for each or maybe it's possible to use delegate. Sure.

So I follow the tutorial from 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx about the event
and 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288459(v=vs.71).aspx about the delegate

And now, I think, it's not possible to create a listener to manager event in Web context.
My assumption is Web is not connected env, so you lost context each time.
Do you know a technical way to manage event+listener with webContext?

If you have any documentation/link about a pattern to implement it will be a plleasure to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your API (Controller action/ WEB API) ‘**context/session aware**’ by using a session Id to refer to the same session. This way your server side logic will be able to ‘remember’ things for you, thus emulating a concept of a context.

This approach falls out of favour when you look at it from scalabilities’ point of view where your request would be served by one of many servers in a server cluster (unless you implement a dedicated session sharing mechanisms).

Best would be to implement a business service layer which would encapsulate all you atomic and repetitive logic and get the controller actions / web apis to call the service methods

hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it can be a good way to use session Id. No other ways to do it. Effectively in the business layer I can encapsule  many things and I need to think my application with this conditions.